# How to print the time of two minutes ago in the format hours and minutes in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to print only the hours and the minutes ("%H:%M") by deleting other informations:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2))
```

- This is the output I get:

2021-06-25 17:52:37.347066

- While, this is the output I'd like to get:

17:52

How can I get this output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Have you tried doing a [web search for your problem?](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+format+time) The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) pretty comprehensively explains how to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a string

```
>>> print((datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2)).strftime("%H:%M"))
20:59
```

Comment: I would add a link to Please [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) of datetime docs since it is rather trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strftime` method of datetime objects

```
two_mins_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2)
print(two_mins_ago.strftime(%H:%M))
```